# Disable vertical scroll in mobile device only fory body (not also for div with overflow: auto)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like disable vertical scroll in all mobile devices and i found this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

that works very well...
but in this way i disable scroll also for a div (my menu) that has `overflow: auto`.

In dekstop browser to avoid anything with **JQuery** when `$(window).scroll()` add `overflow: hidden` to `body`. And in that way i don't have problem, but with native javascript code yes... i'm new in javascript.

So with jquery i was able disable scroll of body eccept div with overflow: auto, but not with that js code.

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i solved always with jQuery:

when i want disable scroll add:

```
    $("body").css({"overflow":"hidden",'position':'fixed'});
```

with `body: fixed` i'm sure that also with mobile device is impossible scroll the page (except div that has `overflow: auto`

Answer (score 0):

you could disable the scrool on just the body part by making it the size of the screen and then make it so it doesnt scrol

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ 
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]. style .height = "100vh";
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]. style. overflow = "hidden";
 });
```